# CDATA in XML and missing values XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0, cdata

I can not get country values to show up in my XSLT transformation and not sure how to deal with the CDATA tag in my XSLT

Here is my XML:

```
<catalog xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
<cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <description><![CDATA[
      <div>
        <b>Country:</b>
        <a href="location.html">Canada</a>
        <b>City:</b>
        <a href="location.html">Calgary</a>
      </div>            
    ]]></description>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <description><![CDATA[
      <div>
        <b>Country:</b>
        <a href="location.html">Canada</a>
        <b>City:</b>
        <a href="location.html">Toronto</a>
      </div>    
    ]]></description>
</cd>
</catalog>
```

Here is my XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
        <p>Title: <xsl:value-of select="title"/></p> 
        <p>Country: <xsl:value-of select="description/div/b['Country:']/following-sibling::a" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></p>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

My Result is:

```
<p>Title: Empire Burlesque</p>
<p>Country: </p> 
<p>Title: Hide your heart</p>
<p>Country: </p>
```

How can I get my country values to show up.  If I remove the CDATA tags from my XML, it works. However, I don't have the ability to modify the XML as it will be coming in from an external feed.

Thanks
Cheers

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor do you use? And is there well-formed XML inside of those CDATA sections? Or will that be HTML? Usually people use CDATA sections to escape data that is not XML.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I ran this code:
<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor')" /> and the result is Apache Software Foundation. From the looks of it, it will be HTML in the CDATA section

Comment: It is difficult even in XSLT 2.0 although there Saxon has extensions or there is a HTML parser implementation done in XSLT 2.0. With XSLT 1.0 if you really want to parse the contents to do XPath on it you will need to check how you can call or implement extension functions to integrate an HTML parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, the authors of the source document do not want you to parse the contents of the `description` element *as XML* - otherwise they would not mark it up as a CDATA section.

However, you can still parse the contents *as text* - although it is more difficult and less robust than the alternative:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
        <p>
            <xsl:text>Title: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        </p> 
        <xsl:variable name="country-anchor" select="substring-before(substring-after(description, '&lt;b&gt;Country:&lt;/b&gt;'), '&lt;b&gt;')" />
        <p>
            <xsl:text>Country: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($country-anchor, '&gt;'), '&lt;')"/>
        </p>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

A better option - if your processing chain allows it - would be to do the transformation in two passes: first, disable output escaping on `description` and save the result to a file; then process the resulting file as XML.

Both of these can be performed with an XSLT 1.0 processor.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it can be done in a clean way with XSLT 2.0 with the commercial versions of Saxon 9 and the help of the TagSoup HTML parser library http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs saxon xhtml"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
            <p>Title: <xsl:value-of select="title"/></p> 
            <p>Country: <xsl:value-of select="saxon:parse-html(description)//xhtml:div/xhtml:b[. = 'Country:']/following-sibling::xhtml:a[1]"/></p>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As an alternative, with any XSLT 2.0 processor you can use an HTML parser implemented by David Carlisle in XSLT 2.0 itself:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:d="data:,dpc"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs saxon xhtml d"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:import href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/master/htmlparse/htmlparse.xsl"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
            <p>Title: <xsl:value-of select="title"/></p> 
            <p>Country: <xsl:value-of select="d:htmlparse(description)//xhtml:div/xhtml:b[. = 'Country:']/following-sibling::xhtml:a[1]"/></p>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we are using XSLT version 1

Answer (score 0):

CDATA means "character data". A CDATA tag means "the stuff in here might look like markup, but don't be fooled, I want it treated as plain text". So someone has boobed here; they've incorrectly used CDATA to enclose stuff that (to you at least) is markup rather than text. I've no idea why people do this, but your only remedy is to repair the damage before processing the data.

Two ways of doing this are:

(a) use plain text processing tools (sed, awk, Perl) to simply remove the start and end CDATA tags from the file before XML parsing. Of course, you can only do this if you know that the content of the CDATA section is actually well-formed XML.

(b) process the XML document as supplied. The CDATA section will appear in your XSLT code as a single text node. To turn this into a node tree you need to parse it as XML (the CDATA tags prevented the enclosed markup being recognized as markup the first time around). You can do this, for example, using the XSLT 3.0 parse-xml() or parse-xml-fragment() functions, or by calling out to extension functions. Again, this relies on knowing that the content is well-formed XML. If it's HTML rather than XML, which is sometimes the case, you can invoke an HTML parser instead of an XML parser.